# Sharing of Databases/Schema on Different machines in Mysql

Tags: database, shared, saas, multi-tenant

I have been working on a multi tenancy architecture application, decided to go with the per database per tenant architecture. I search for how to scale databases and access across multiple database machines, but didn't find any reliable solution.

Scenario is I want to share databases of tenants across multiple machines, like db_t1 on machine1 db_t1023 on machine2. Can I setup some sort of Cluster so that this can be achieved? Or any other possible cloud based or software based solution, that can be transparent to the application.